# Read the latest csv with pattern

Tags: r, csv, import

I am trying to write a code to import the latest .csv files to R. They should be three. First, the latest .csv file containing expression "abc_def310", second, latest .csv file containing expression "abc_def223" and third file would be the latest .csv containing expression "abc_def331".

So far I have managed to order .csv files in the directory according to their creation time. How to continue?

```
data_files <- file.info(Sys.glob("*.csv"))
ordered<-row.names(data_files)[order(data_files$ctime)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the file are ordered by time, we can use `grep` to find filenames with a particular word and to get latest file we use `max`

```
data_files <- file.info(Sys.glob("*.csv"))
ordered<-row.names(data_files)[order(data_files$ctime)]

first_file <- max(grep('abc_def310', ordered))
second_file <- max(grep('abc_def223', ordered))
third_file<- max(grep('abc_def331', ordered))

latest_files <- lapply(ordered[c(first_file, second_file, third_file)], read.csv)
```

Comment: Thank you. And if I wanted second latest files how would it change?

Comment: Use `head` and `tail` then.`tail(grep('abc_def310', ordered), 1)[1]` would gives you latest file, `tail(grep('abc_def310', ordered), 2)[1]` second latest. `head(grep('abc_def310', ordered), 1)[1]` would give you oldest file and so on.